# WLS REST API to GET JNDI tree

Tags: jndi, weblogic11g

I want to pull the JNDI configuration from WebLogic server, that has been assigned to a particular application deployed on server,

Does anyone know what WebLogic API I should curl to GET JNDI keys:values or entire TREE

Please help, the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLRUR/using.htm#WLRUR180 doesn't tell anything...

I don't know even how to explain the problem, documentation about how to access information from WLS is just a DUMP

There are a lot about JNDI but nothing on how run API to get JNDI
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WJNDI/index.html#WJNDI115
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50629_01/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/jndi/ViewObjectsInTheJNDITree.html
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLRUR/using.htm#WLRUR157
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wls/WJNDI/jndi.htm#WJNDI136

Thanks

Comment: Sound like no one knows what is JNDI, WebLogic Server, REST API, etc.. XD

Comment: NDI trees are not exposed through REST APIs.

Comment: Oh they are, and I have found the solution, check out the classes api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a solution, check out the classes API. it prints the JNDI parameters for all deployed applications,

http://localhost:7001/management/weblogic/latest/serverConfig/startupClasses

Thanks for all your negative marks... pf... professionals!!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).